# Google Apps Script Overflow Error - Result Set Too Large

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to query Google Finance for the high stock price for during the entire time a particular stock has been held.  The one stock purchased in 2000 can be excluded.  The rest of the portfolio purchases have been from 12-31-2004 thru present day.  The result set appears to be too large for the following script.

Is there a way to break this into separate API calls resulting in smaller result sets but still providing historical data back to 12-31-2004?

```
 function stockHigh(ticker, startDate, endDate) {
 //returns https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_financeresult
 var financeResult = FinanceApp.getHistoricalStockInfo(
   ticker, startDate, endDate, 1);

 var high = 0;
 for(var i in financeResult.stockInfo) {
   var stockInfo = financeResult.stockInfo[i];
   high = Math.max(high, stockInfo.high);
 }
 return high;
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply load the data in a spreadsheet and perform the search for the max result in this spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that.  There are numerous stocks that are always changing.  Having a summary sheet that uses a script to load the data in real time would be ideal.  It was working until 2014 rolled over and the result set apparently became too large for some of the stocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the class financeapp was deprecated ? Should we still be using it and if not what should we use?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/finance-app